# Using .then inside async parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, sequelize.js, async.js

I'm trying to run two sequelize queries inside async.parallel so I can then pass them in the callback to a form (though form integration not shown here). When I run this it returns the results.animals, but results.zones is undefined.

I can see from the log that it's running the Zone.findAll at the end after the async.parallel callback function has already run. If I only do one sequelize call in zones then it works, but not when I query for a state.findOne and then Zone.findAll.

Any idea why this is happening? I thought async.parallel was supposed to wait for both to finish before returning?

```
async.parallel({
        animals: function(callback) { 
                    Animal.findAll().then(function(animalResult){
                        console.log("animals result: " + JSON.stringify(animalResult))
                        callback(null, animalResult);
                    })
                }, 
        zones: function(callback){
                    State.findOne({
                        where : { abbr : req.query.state.toUpperCase() }
                    }).then(function(state) {
                        console.log("State ID: " + JSON.stringify(state['id']))
                        Zone.findAll({
                            attributes: ['name'],
                            where: { StateId : state['id']}
                        })
                    }).then(function(zoneResult) {
                        console.log("zones result: " + JSON.stringify(zoneResult));
                        callback(null, zoneResult);
                    });
                }
        }, function(err, results) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            console.log("Results in callback: " + JSON.stringify(results));
            res.send(results)
        }
    );
```

Comment: Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52575856/how-to-make-async-code-into-sync-inside-the-async-parallel-method-nodejs/52576712#52576712

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to have the results of both (or may be even more) queries available in your form at the same time, you can use Promise.join in the following manner:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize(dbName, username, ...);

var getAnimals = function(){
  return Animal.findAll({ where: { name: 'xyz' }});
}

var getZones = function(){
  return State.findOne({ where: { abbr : req.query.state.toUpperCase() }})
        .then(function(state){ 
            return Zone.findAll({ where: { StateId : state['id']} }});
        });
}

// now use Promise.join to execute the 2 functions concurrently and
// have their result in the handler function
sequelize.Promise.join(getAnimals(), getZones(), function(animals, zones){
  // animals and zones are sequelize instances
  console.log(animals.someProperty);
  console.log(zones.someProperty);
  res.json({ animals: animals, zones: zones });
});
```